# String array plus string is not error, why?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string

I came across the code similar to the following:

```
var a = (new string [] {}) + string.Empty;
```

I would like to ask:

- Why this code can be compiled (why isn`t this error of types) ?
- How to understand this behavior ?

Comment: in that case c# will call the default method `.ToString()` on `(new string [] {})` because of the concatenation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 3 [`+`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1a63xkz.aspx) operator overload in .NET Framework.

From C# Spec [$7.8.4 Addition operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691375%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
string operator + (string x, string y);
string operator + (string x, object y);
string operator + (object x, string y);
```

That's why your `var a = (new string [] {}) + string.Empty;` matches the third overload.

And `+ (object x, string y)` uses [`String.Concat(object, object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbseaaft%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload which is [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs#394d9acb24f287b2) like;

```
public static String Concat(Object arg0, Object arg1)
{ 
     if (arg0 == null)
     {
         arg0 = String.Empty;
     }

     if (arg1==null) {
         arg1 = String.Empty;
     }
     return Concat(arg0.ToString(), arg1.ToString());
}
```

And since `new string [] {}` is not `null` because in MSIL, it uses [`newarr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.newarr%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and it's documentation;

> The stack transitional behavior, in sequential order, is:
>
> 1. The number of elements in the array is pushed onto the stack.
> 2. The number of elements is popped from the stack and the array is created.
> 3. **An object reference to the new array is pushed onto the stack.**

That's why it uses [`object.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method at the end.

From it's documentation;

> ToString is the major formatting method in the .NET Framework. It
>   converts an object to its string representation so that it is suitable
>   for display.**The default implementation of the ToString method returns the fully 
>   qualified name of the type**

As a result your `a` will be `System.String[]`.

Answer (score 4):

The C# Language Specification has an overload

```
string operator +(object x, string y)
```

which works by calling `x.ToString()` (if `x` is not null, otherwise just use `""`) and concatenate that with `y`.

Therefore your code should produce the same as

```
string a = string.Concat((new string[] {}).ToString(), string.Empty);
```

so now the question is how `ToString()` is implemented on the `string[]` type. It turns out that it is not overridden from the implementation from `object`.

Answer (score 2):

It compiles because the `+` operator will call `string[].ToString` which is [`object.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which returns the name of the type. So the meaningless result is `"System.String[]"`:

```
 string[] abc = { "a", "b", "c" };
 string a = abc + string.Empty;  // --> System.String[]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = (new String[] {"a", "b"}) + " ABD";
```

It will call toString() method on `new String[] {"a", "b"}` array object and concatenate it with string " ABD".